# What is a good way to make small audio edits to a very large mp4 file?

Tags: audio, editing, mp4

I have a video that I'd like to remove a few small things from its audio (coughs, phone vibrations, etc.). It's an mp4 and it's rather huge (over 4GB), and I'm not finding an editor that can manage to open it.

These changes are rather minor, so I'd like something that's free, easy to use, and runs on Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You first have to find an editor that can open it, or convert it to a format, an editor you like supports.

Comment: What editors have you tried and does your system have the guts to handle that large a video file?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have enough memory, find a way to separate the audio and video tracks into separate files, then decrease the quality on the video, creating a new video file (but keeping the original), and then use your editor to open both the low quality video and the audio. Edit the audio. Save the audio. Then comes the final part, combining them together, into your product file.

There's loads of tools for this, and I'm out of the loop for a while, so I can't recommend, but this should work.

You should worry about not changing timestamps (stuff like file lenghts). Also, if you don't need the video to edit the audio, just skip the part where you convert the video to low quality and just edit the audio.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and tried several ways and all of them need to render the whole video.

Comment: another way of doing it: convert your video to low quality. Do all your editions on the low quality video and store them as a macro.Apply that macro to the main file. There are scripting languages for this.

Comment: converting the video is playing the same role. Theoretically we want to just manipulate a small set of bits that relates to the sound of that section and we have nothing to do with other bits. So the efficient practical way (which I hope to exist) is to just render that section and leave other sections untouched.

Comment: unless you get lucky with stuff like primary frames, or editing raw formats, that won't happen :)

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Of what I said,what you wana do?

Comment: we can edit only a specific section of the video by accessing its "primary frames, or editing raw formats"? how?

Comment: A raw format implies that you have an image for each frame. And you could use a splitter to cut the video into desired parts anywhere and open them in a normal computer and edit normally and then put it back together. But that also implies huge huge files.
In non-raw formats, something like virtual dub can tell you which frames are primary. You can safely split the video around those frames. Everything else is unsafe to cut. The proces will be the same. Split, edit, put back together.
But you know, "editing" is a very meta word. I have no idea what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I know that [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can separate the audio stream from an MP4 file, and there should be a way to use it to combine audio from one file with video from another. The `mencoder` tool from [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/info.html) should be able to do those conversions as well.  [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) uses a directory of files on disk to hold raw data while editing audio, so it shouldn't be limited by RAM.